# How to not update ValidFrom - ValidTo table field?

Tags: axapta, utc, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have to update a record on Table with **ValidTimeStateFieldType** *UTCDateTime*, but I need to Update only a string field.
If I use this code:

```
while select forUpdate MyTable
{
  MyTable.StringField = "Test";
  MyTable_UPD.validTimeStateUpdateMode(ValidTimeStateUpdate::EffectiveBased);

  ttsbegin;
  MyTable.update();
  ttscommit;
}
```

After command `MyTable.update();` change the value on table MyTable.ValidFrom or MyTable.ValidTo.
I need to change only the value on *StringField*, I don't need to change the values on ValidFrom/To. I want to preserve the same information on UTC field and I don't want to create a new record.

If I use `MyTable.validTimeStateUpdateMode(ValidTimeStateUpdate::Correction);` I receive an error.

It's possible to change only value and don't touch anything on ValueFrom/To field?

Thanks,

enjoy!

Comment: What is the error you are getting when using ValidTimeStateUpdate::Correction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken it is not possible to modify only your `StringField` because in your **table** in ***Indexes*** you have defined `DateTime` field.

You need use `validTimeStateUpdateMode` function, in your code use `MyTable` and then `MyTable.update()` but you use `validTimeStateUpdateMode(ValidTimeStateUpdate::EffectiveBased);`
 in `MyTable_UPD` not `MyTable`.

**Try This:**

```
ttsbegin;
while select forUpdate MyTable
{
    MyTable.StringField = "Test";
    MyTable.validTimeStateUpdateMode(ValidTimeStateUpdate::Correction);
    MyTable.update();

}
ttscommt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a valid time state range in your select statement.

Something like this:

```
MyTable.validTimeStateUpdateMode(ValidTimeStateUpdate::Correction);

ttsbegin;
while select forUpdate validTimeState(1\1\1900, 31\12\2154) * from MyTable
{
  MyTable.StringField = "Test";
  MyTable.update();
}
ttscommit;
```

I used examples from this MSDN page for help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg843767.aspx